# Pattern Matching in Unix

Tags: perl, bash, unix

1st File

```
D07        AAS@qqq
B82        GG^333
D84        GG@WW
F59        LL$$EE
```

2nd File

```
D84        /usr/ss
F59        /usr/jh
B82        /usr/kk
D07        /usr/ks
```

Output should be

```
D84     GG@WW       /usr/ss
F59     LL$$EE    /usr/jh
B82     GG^333      /usr/kk
D07     AAS@qqq     /usr/ks
```

Basically , I want to get the data of 1st file sorted a w.r.t to 2nd File

I tried with :

```
BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = "\t";
}
NR==FNR {
   Values[$1+0] = $2;
   next;
}
{
   $1 = $1 OFS ($1+0 in Values ? Values[$1+0] : "");
   print $0;
}
' 1stfile 2ndfile
```

Can anyone give any easy solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need perl if you are willing to sort the files and then use bash `join`

```
$ ll
file1
file2
$ cat file1
D07        AAS@qqq
D82        GG^333
D84        GG@WW
D59        LL$$EE
$ cat file2
D84        /usr/ss
D59        /usr/jh
D82        /usr/kk
D07        /usr/ks
$ sort -n file1 > file1a
$ sort -n file2 > file2a
$ cat file1a
D07        AAS@qqq
D59        LL$$EE
D82        GG^333
D84        GG@WW
$ cat file2a
D07        /usr/ks
D59        /usr/jh
D82        /usr/kk
D84        /usr/ss
$ join file1a file2a > file3
$ cat file3
D07 AAS@qqq /usr/ks
D59 LL$$EE /usr/jh
D82 GG^333 /usr/kk
D84 GG@WW /usr/ss
```

Comment: Just updated the issue...if the data not sorted ... can you please help me in this..

Comment: Is it a problem when you sort first? Or will that mess up what you want to do?

Comment: @Chronicles: One step, no temp files: `join <(sort -nd file1) <(sort -nd file2)`

Comment: don't understand why -nd options -k1 seems more direct

Answer (score 0):

with perl:

```
perl -nle '/(.*?)\s+(.*)/&&($h{$1}[$t]=$2);eof&&$t++;END{while(($k,$v)=each%h){print"$k @{$v}"}}' 1stfile 2ndfile
```